# Why is uWSGI incapable of locating the functools module for Flask?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, debian, uwsgi

I want to know how to run a Flask web application inside uWSGI with virtualenv. I have a global installation of uWSGI and Flask is installed with pip inside the virtual environment directory for my project.

I am getting the following error when starting up `uwsgi` in emperor mode:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/myapp/MyModule/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
  File "/var/www/myapp/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
  File "/var/www/myapp/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from werkzeug._compat import iteritems
  File "/var/www/myapp/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/_compat.py", line 3, in <module>
    import functools
ImportError: No module named functools
```

My **emperor.ini** file looks like this:

```
[uwsgi]
daemonize = /var/log/uwsgi/emperor.log
touch-logreopen = /etc/uwsgi/logrotate.trigger
emperor = /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled
pidfile = /var/run/uwsgi/emperor.pid
die-on-term = true
```

My **/etc/uwsgi/apps-available/myapp.ini** file looks like this:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:9000
wsgi-file = /var/www/myapp/MyModule/__init__.py
virtualenv = /var/www/myapp/environment/
pythonpath = /var/www/myapp/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages
pythonpath = /var/www/myapp/MyModule/
callable = app
no-site = True
processes = 4
threads = 2
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/myapp.log
```

This file is symlinked to **/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/myapp.ini**

For completeness, I am using systemd to manage the service on Debian 7.7 and my startup file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled --uid www-data --gid www-data
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]t
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What I have tried:

- Not running in emperor mode got the same error as running in emperor mode
- Using Flask's embedded server, which actually worked fine
- Switching between python 2.7 and python 3.2 in the virtual environment, which produced errors that it couldn't load a **different** module
- Rebuilt the VM, reinstalled Debian, followed a detailed nginx + uwsgi + flask guide
- Running an app that isn't using Flask, a basic hello world, and it worked fine without changing uwsgi or nginx configurations
- Changing myapp.ini to use and also omit `no-site`; omitting it causes an error about not being able to load a module named site
- Using the myapp.ini module declaration like so: module = MyModule:app, same issue
- Changing up the application directory structure, originally using a wsgi.py just outside of the module directory (/var/www/myapp/wsgi.py)
- Scouring the Internet for answers for over 7 hours now

How do I fix this?

**EDIT 1**

I'm still working on this and I've removed the `no-site` option but have not been able to get it to run beyond that. I initially thought it might be a permissions issue with having created the virtualenv from a different user, but after running chown it still shows the error of **ImportError: No module named site**.

I also tried creating a simple hello world Flask application and put my **hello.py** file inside the virtualenv directory since I saw that recommendation in a forum, it didn't help. I set `no-site = True` and I still see **ImportError: No module named flask**. Still, the application runs fine by activating the virtualenv and running `python hello.py` with the built-in web server.

Comment: never use no-site unless you know what you are doing. Check the python version used by uWSGI (it is printed in the initial logs), it must be the same of the virtualenv. If they differ, you will get the site module error (it is the standard python behaviour when mixing environments)

Comment: @roberto I activate the virtualenv and "Python 2.7.3 [GCC 4.7.2] on linux2". I deactivate the virtualenv and it's the exact same build down to the timestamp. However, I did notice that uWSGI says something abvout mixed interpreter mode. The system has a few different versions of Python installed but the one running in the virtualenv is the default for the system. I also created the virtualenv with `-p /usr/bin/python2` which is linked to python2.7. I originally thought that was the case and that it would be an easy fix. I only used no-site because it got at least into Flask's code base.

Comment: activating/deactivating the venv is useless (it only set environment variables in the current session). uWSGI takes care of it. Please check the python version used by uWSGI, it must be the same of your virtualenv.

Comment: @roberto I just said the virtualenv's python version (you activate, then run python and look at the version string) is equal to the system python version and is also equal to the one mentioned in the uwsgi log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-imaged the system to Arch Linux to remove as many variables as possible, downloaded and built uWSGI from source, got around to installing a specific Python version and realized Python 3.2 isn't supported by Flask. When I installed it on Debian, it installed with Python 3.2 and Arch's package has 3.4.2. Since 3.4.x is supported by Flask, the problem was solved.

As far as Python 2.7 not working, I have no idea.